# Coffeescript strict comparisons

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, strict, comparison-operators

I have the following code:

```
$(document).bind 'gform_confirmation_loaded', (event, form_id) =>
  if form_id == 3
    // Do stuff here
...
```

If I run:

```
typeof form_id
```

I get :

```
number
```

Of course the same is true for:

```
typeof 3
```

However, when the value of 3 is passed in for form_id the comparison returns false.

Coffeescript changes abstract comparison to a strict one when it compiles. If I modify the output to an abstract comparison the if statement returns true.

Given the type and value are equal, the if statement should be returning true with a strict comparison I would think?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you passing "the value of 3" for form_id?

Comment: @MattBall Its an event fired after an ajax form submission. Details: http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/gravity-forms/extending-gravity-forms/hooks/filters/gform_confirmation_loaded/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you get `Number` for `typeof 3`, `typeof 3` is `'number'` and that's not the same thing as [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number). In JavaScript, if you have `a = 3` and `b = new Number(3)`, then:

```
a == b   // true
a === b  // false
typeof a // 'number'
typeof b // Number
```

Of course in CoffeeScript, `==` is JavaScript's `===` so `a == b` will be `false` in CoffeeScript. Sound familiar?

I think your library is giving you `new Number(3)`. If that's the case then you could get a plain old number using `Number(form_id)`:

```
if Number(form_id) == 3
  # Do stuff here
```

Comment: I have updated the question - what I actually get as a typeof for both is number (not Number).